# Redirect Loop NGINX

Tags: wordpress, nginx

Hey guys this is my first time posting a question here.

I have a problem, I'm tired I been trying all day and cant make it work
My website says redirect loop or problem when the other sites work except for 1 and its the same configuration. If you guys could help me I'd be grateful.

Long story short, I have 2 domains with some subdomains:

(SITE NOT READY YET WILL BE WORDPRESS) proyectosx.net --> 104.156.48.17 
(PHPMYADMN SITE) phpmyadmin.proyectosx.net --> 104.156.48.17

(WORKING SMF FORUM READY WORKS FINE) forum.proyectosx.net --> 104.156.48.18

*PROBLEM SITE* (WORDPRESS NOT READY YET BUT HAS FILES READY TO SETUP) spartansvs.net --> 104.156.48.19

This are working:

```html
server {
    listen 104.156.48.17:80;
    server_name phpmyadmin.proyectosx.net;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 104.156.48.17:443 ssl;
    server_name phpmyadmin.proyectosx.net;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate ssl/phpmyadmin.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key ssl/phpmyadmin.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains";

    root /usr/share/nginx/phpmyadmin/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

**This one also works**

```html
server {
    listen 104.156.48.18:80;
    server_name forum.proyectosx.net;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 104.156.48.18:443 ssl;
    server_name forum.proyectosx.net;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate ssl/forumsx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key ssl/forumsx.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains";

    root /usr/share/nginx/forumsx/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

**This one DOESN'T WORK**

```html
server {
    listen 104.156.48.19:80;
    server_name spartansvs.net;
    return 301 https://spartansvs.net$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 104.156.48.19:80;
    server_name www.spartansvs.net;
    return 301 https://spartansvs.net$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 104.156.48.19:443 ssl;
    server_name spartansvs.net;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate ssl/spartan.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key ssl/spartan.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains";

    root /usr/share/nginx/spartan/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Hopefully I was clear guys also I want to make that if people put IP on the address bar of their browser instead of domain for example if they put 104.156.48.17 on the address bar it goes to the phpmyadmin I know its assigned to that IP but I don't want them to do that I don't know how to block that I payed someone 20 dollars to help me and he never accomplished anything :(
Please help me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please split off at least your last question into a different posting. Also, this would probably work better on [SF].

Comment: Thanks for that I didn't knew.